# Combine htaccess rewrites

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

I am using php CodeIgniter and have the following rewrite rule in my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Since I want the users to use the site through SSL, I would like to add the following rewrite rule:

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.link.com/$1 [R,L]
```

However, when I do that, every page in a subdirectory will have /index.php/actual_page - the index.php before that is not desired. I thought that might come from having `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]` in there, but without the `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.link.com/$1 [R,L]` it works fine.

So, how can I rewrite the url to https without breaking the first rewrite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the https redirect happens before the rewrite to index.php. You want it to look something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.link.com/$1 [R,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```